# Copy images in subfolders to another directory with subfolders using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

I have a folder with many subfolders that contain images. 
I split the data using `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` same as below:

```
folder_data_train, folder_data_test, train_target, test_target =
train_test_split(data, targets_array, test_size=0.20, random_state=42, shuffle = True, stratify = targets_array)
```

folder_data_test is include .png images. 
output of print(folder_data_test) is:

```
['/avi_images/A4CH_RV\\12505310b836710d_c18.png'
 '/avi_images/PLAX_valves\\6ad39d497bc07141_c21.png'
 '/avi_images/A4CH_LV\\7f50b7e4c051d48f_b52.png' ...
 '/avi_images/Suprasternal\\6978b0ee7068a69e_b37.png'
 '/avi_images/A5CH\\61cabd1291a81fc8_b43.png'
 '/avi_images/PLAX_full\\2cab9cf0dd8d6480_b7.png']
```

I want to copy these images from `folder_data_test` to new directory including subfolders. for example subfloder is `A4CH_RV`. My current code is:

```
dst_dir_test = '/avi_images_search/test/'

for testdata in folder_data_test: 
    shutil.copy(testdata, dst_dir_test)
```

it is copying all images from `folder_data_test` to `dst_dir_test` directory without subfolder. How can I copy them to the relevant subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

`shutil` acts almost like shell in this case.

Your code does this (for each file) :

```
shutil.copy('/avi_images/A4CH_RV\\12505310b836710d_c18.png', '/avi_images_search/test/')
```

This is rougthly equivalent to

```
cp /avi_images/A4CH_RV\\12505310b836710d_c18.png /avi_images_search/test/
```

I'm a little bit confused by the `\\`, but I guess you are on windows and what you want is

```
cp /avi_images/A4CH_RV\\12505310b836710d_c18.png /avi_images_search/test/A4CH_RV
```

To do this in python you'll have to play around with the path, and create the directory before the copy.

```
src_base_path = '/avi_images/'
for testdata in folder_data_test:
    [src_dir_path,file_name] = os.path.split(testdata)
    sub_dir = os.path.join(dst_dir_test, src_dir_path[len(src_base_path):])
    os.makedirs(sub_dir, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(testdata, sub_dir)
```

I didn't try it, but it should be something along those lines.